# Select Checkbox when its Value Equals the String from the EditText field

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, expandablelistview

**Problem:** In my app, there exists two different ways for a user to add an item to a list: via a TextField and via checking an element in an ExpandableListView. Every time the user enters an item into the TextField, I would like to check if that value appears within any group of the ExpandableListView. If it does, then I would like to check that item.

**Implementation of Solution:** I have a HashMap that stores as keys all the values within the ExpandableListView, and its values are the corresponding group HashMap in which they are in. If the item is found then I plan to derive its location by using a second HashMap that stores its position within the group.

**Question:** Using this information, how can I check/uncheck that particular box? Specifically how can I identify a particular child of the ExpandableListView, and then identify a child of that?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is slightly different but it does the work.
Each element of yours must have a `HashMap`. Considering adding another element to it.
A string element call it `ChkVal` default value in it is `false`.

Now when you match the value from textbox to the element in that group. Using the `hashmap`.
Change its `checkbox` value.

```
Boolean b = false;
String chkCondition = hmap.get(chk).toString().toLowerCase();
if (chkCondition.equals("true"))
     b = true;
chkBox.setChecked(b);
```

Comment: Hi MDMalik, thank you for your response. Do you think you could add your approach/code to the way you solved this problem?

Comment: @jsc123 this is my approach. if you could post your code i would easily show where does this code above fits